# How can I split a data frame in R randomly?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with ca. 1000 rows, and I want to split it randomly into 8 smaller dataframes each containing 100 element. I tried to used the `sample` function 8 times on the data frame, but sometimes it selects the same rows.

Comment: Another approach may be `split(df, sample(rep(1:10, each=100)))[1:8]` but I can't currently test it.

Comment: or randomly order, select 800 `split(df1[order(runif(1000))[1:800], ], 1:8)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We create a grouping variable by `sample`ing 1 to 8 with `size` as the number of rows of the dataset, `split` the sequence of rows with the grouping variable in a `list`, loop through the `list` (`lapply(...`), subset the dataset and get the first 100 rows with `head`

```
lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(df1), sample(1:8, nrow(df1), replace=TRUE, prob = rep(1/8, 8))),
           function(i) head(df1[i,],100))
sapply(lst, nrow)
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
#100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

As @RHertel mentioned in the comments, we can do a second `sample` to get the 100 rows

```
lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(df1), sample(1:8, nrow(df1), replace=TRUE, prob = rep(1/8, 8))),
       function(i) df1[sample(i, 100, replace=FALSE),])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(V1= 1:1000, V2= rnorm(1000))
```

Comment: is 24 your favorite number @akrun?

Comment: @RHertel Thanks for the comments.  I think it makes sense.  Included that.